# How can I query all products with their variation attributes?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have following database schema:

[image: database schema]

Django models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    # price and so on

class Size(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
class Color(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="variations")
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So I can write:

```
product.variations
```

But I also want to be able to write

```
product.sizes

product.colors
```

to get all sizes or colors that this product has in variation table

The problem that I'm trying to solve: I have product card list. And each card has options of sizes and colors to choose and to add to user's cart. I want to show the user sizes and colors that this particular product has in database to not list all the sizes and colors from database.

[image]

But variations can have duplicates, for example, consider these combinations for some random product:

size - 40, color - red

size - 42, color - green

size - 44, color - red (again)

size - 42 (again), color - gray

I want to show the user
sizes: 40, 42, 44

colors: red, green, gray

At the moment I'm showing all of them with duplicates like

sizes: 40, 42, 44, 42

colors: red, green, red, gray

It is produced by this code and I don't know how to rewrite it:

```
products: QuerySet[Product] = (
    Product.objects
        .prefetch_related("variations__size")
        .prefetch_related("variations__color")
        .all()[:15]
)
```

Then I iterate over products in my template without producing extra queries like

```
{% for variation in product.variations.all %}
    variation.size.value
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does using set() accomplish what you are trying  to do?            products: QuerySet[Product] = set((
    Product.objects
        .prefetch_related("variations__size")
        .prefetch_related("variations__color")
        .all()[:15])
)

Comment: No, Adam. You didn't understand

Comment: but product.variations.sizes does not work?

Comment: I would say your two best bets would be to put a method in your model that returns a list or dictionary that you can loop through for these items or a custom template tag.

Comment: product.variations - it is RelationManager which return all rows in Variation table. Can I create custom relationManager that will return not all rows, but only the ones I want

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found a solution:

I used Prefetch object and its 3rd argument to_attr:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

```
products: QuerySet[Product] = (
    Product.objects
        .prefetch_related(Prefetch(
            "variations",
            queryset=Variation.objects
                .select_related("size")
                .select_related("color")
                .distinct("color"),
            to_attr="color_variations",
        ))
        .prefetch_related(Prefetch(
            "variations",
            queryset=Variation.objects
                .select_related("size")
                .select_related("color")
                .distinct("size"),
            to_attr="size_variations",
        ))
        .all()[:15]
)
```